# Pre checked check box

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I have a site that has multiple ways to access our "email me for more information" form.
On the form, it has a list of checkboxes that they can check that they want to be emailed about more information for. Is it possible to have the check box prechecked depending on what page they come from?

For example, they visit our "Product 12" page and follow the link to the form and there is a checkbox to receive more information on Product 12 that is pre-checked because they came to the form from the Product 12 page.

Here is my form code:

```
<form id="formElem" name="formElem" action="" method="post">
  <fieldset class="step">
    <legend>Personal Details</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="fullname">Full Name</label>
      <input id="fullname" name="username" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="company">Company Name</label>
      <input id="company" name="company" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="title">Title</label>
      <input id="title" name="title" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
      <input id="phone" name="phone" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="info@.com" type="email" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="step">
    <legend>Products I'm interested in...</legend>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="telematics" value="telematics">Telematics<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="controllers" value="controllers">Controllers<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="cots" value="cots">Custom-off-the-Shelf<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="displays" value="displays">Displays\Operator Interfaces<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="cordReels" value="cordreels">Cord Reels<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="pdm" value="pdm">Power Distribution Modules<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="rtc" value="rtc">Real Time Clock<br>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="step">
    <legend>Services I'm interested in...</legend>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="productDev" value="productdev">Product Development<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="desEng" value="deseng">Design Engineering<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="dfx" value="dfx">DFX<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="transServices" value="transServices">Transition Services<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="stratSourcing" value="stratSourcing">Strategic Sourcing<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="planning" value="planning">Planning<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="manufacturing" value="manufacturing">Manufacturing<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="fullfillment" value="fullfillment">Fullfillment<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="prodLifecycle" value="prodLifecycle">Product Life-Cycle Management<br>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="step">
    <legend>Confirm</legend>
  <p>Everything in the form was correctly filled 
   if all the steps have a green checkmark icon.
   A red checkmark icon indicates that some field 
   is missing or filled out with invalid data.
  </p>
    <p class="submit">
      <button id="registerButton" type="submit">Register</button>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

The serverside code will be PHP.

Plz respond.

Comment: Have you attempted something yet? Are you using any kind of server-side language such as PHP or ASP?

Comment: It largely depends how they arrive at the page in question, and whether you have server-side scripting ability. You might look into `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` with PHP, but this really can't be relied upon. Alternatively, you could set a session variable to the last item viewed.

Comment: _"Is it possible to have the check box prechecked depending on what page they come from?"_ Yes. What have you tried? If anything you'll need to provide more details and code.

Comment: Yes, This can be definitely done. But you need to provide some HTML markup so we can show you how its done.

Comment: If you're are using a server-side programming language, sent the parameters via `GET` request to the form page, then check the correspond checkbox. But, If you want to do anything in client-side, get the `GET` parameters from url via JavaScript, and then check the correspond checkbox.

Comment: The server side will have PHP. But I'm not very familiar with PHP.
I also edited my initial submission to add in my form code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I was in your shoes, I would use a query string variable to pass the ID of your page (or product ID would be ideal) on the link linking your product page to the form.

ie.) /formPage.html?id=12

On the form page, give each input element a unique ID. Then using either server side code or javascript, check if the id is present in the querystring, if so, check what it is and programatically check your checkbox.

It's easy with jquery:

$("#product12ID").prop("checked", true); <---- This will check the checkbox that has an id=product12ID

It would be helpful to know what language you're using (ASP.NET, PHP, etc).  It would help fine tune what direction to go in.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will be using PHP.

Comment: I'm a .NET guy, so I don't know exactly how to do it in PHP.  I updated my answer to show how to do it using jquery.  The same process I mentioned would work for php though.